# What curfews, if any, exist in Myanmar at present?

Tags: legal, event-based-effects, myanmar, curfews

I am currently looking to travel to Myanmar (Burma) and had read about some curfews. I was wondering if this is still the case because I couldn't find a great deal of information on them being lifted in all places?

Answer (score 9):

The UK Foreign & Commonwealth Office note that [night time curfews still exist in many areas but can change at short notice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/burma/safety-and-security). You are advised to make inquiries locally about any existing curfews.

> A night-time curfew remains in place in parts of central and northern Rakhine State, including Sittwe and Mrauk U, between 10pm and 5am. Timings of the curfew are liable to change at short notice. Seek local advice and follow any official instructions.
>
> After violence earlier this year in Meiktila, the government imposed a state of emergency and a night-time curfew. Although the state of emergency in Meiktila has been lifted the night time curfew remains in place. Timings of the curfew are liable to change at short notice.
>
> Following unrest in areas of Pago division from 24 March, the government has imposed night-time curfews and other restrictions on public gatherings in several townships in western Pago division. Be alert to further announcements by the Burmese government and monitor local developments.

Answer (score 3):

In big cities like Yangon,Bagan and Mandalay, I don't see any night-time curfew. 
But since electricity is limited, most of lights are off.